# Set customBackoff for AWS SDK JavaScript V3 retries

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, retry-logic, exponential-backoff, aws-sdk-js-v3

I just upgraded to AWS SDK V3 and I have no idea how to configure retryDelayOptions and customBackoff with it. I couldn't find any example code in AWS's own API reference or online. This is what I was doing previously:

```
retryDelayOptions: { customBackoff: (retryCount) => 2 ** (retryCount * 100) },
maxRetries: 2
```

I was passing the above as options into the client constructor. The retries seems to have changed quite a bit with V3 and I cannot make sense of the API without any examples. Any help is much appreciated

Regards,
Deepak

Comment: Note that `^` is a bitwise operator - I believe you intended to use `**`

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out

```
const { StandardRetryStrategy } = require("@aws-sdk/middleware-retry");

module.exports = (maxAttempts)  => 
    new StandardRetryStrategy(async () => maxAttempts, {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-bitwise
        delayDecider: (delayBase, attempts) => 2 ** (attempts * 100)
    })
```

and then you can pass this as retryStrategy

Comment: Thanks!

Unfortunately, the api is deprecated.
You should now use [@aws-sdk/util-retry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_util_retry.html) instead.

But looking at the docs there, it is not obvious how to configure custom backoff.

Comment: Note that `^` is a bitwise operator - I believe you intended to use `**`

Answer (score 2):

As @philipp commented, the `@aws-sdk/middleware-retry` lib is deprecated, the way to set it up right now it is using `@aws-sdk/util-retry` lib.

To configure it can be found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/packages/util-retry)

```js
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { ConfiguredRetryStrategy } from "@aws-sdk/util-retry";

const client = new S3Client({
  retryStrategy: new ConfiguredRetryStrategy(
    4, // max attempts.
    (attempt: number) => 100 + attempt * 1000 // backoff function.
  ),
});
```